# textSwitcher with fade

Tags: android

I set a TextSwitcher using R.anim.fade_in and out. When I click on button I see the text, next click I see no text visible (like fade out), next click text is ok, again next, test is not visible. Where's my error?

```
mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.switcher);
      mSwitcher.setFactory(this);

      Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in);
      Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out);
      mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
      mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);

mSwitcher.setText(""+prog[x]);
```

Comment: an array: prog[0]="one",prog[1]="two"

Comment: what happen if x index is out of range?

Comment: nullpointer exception. why? App runs but I've a problem like above.

Comment: because in documentation says that user see animation on every call setText()

Comment: follow this example http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsesaTextSwitcher.htm I done my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is just a simple example with `fix` in implementing ViewFactory and safe incremeneting counter to get proper element from array of strings.

Main:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, ViewFactory {

    private TextSwitcher mSwitcher;
    private int counter = 0;
    private String[] words = new String[]{"one","two","three"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textswitcher);
        mSwitcher.setFactory(this);

        Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_in);

        Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                android.R.anim.fade_out);
        mSwitcher.setInAnimation(in);
        mSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out);

        Button nextButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        nextButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        updateCounter();
    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        counter++;
        updateCounter();
    }

    private void updateCounter() {
        int index = counter % words.length;
        mSwitcher.setText(String.valueOf(words[index]));
    }

    public View makeView() {
        TextView t = new TextView(this);
        t.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        t.setTextSize(36);
        return t;
    }
}
```

And xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextSwitcher
        android:id="@+id/textswitcher"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="next" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Displaying won't work well if you want call element with out of range in your array of elements... Please take note on it.